# Firing a GridView RowCommand event from a Button inside a Template Field - C#

Tags: c#, gridview, bootstrap-modal, rowcommand

So I have a GridView (`gvSummary`) which contains a template field with a button inside (`btnOpen`). This button's purpose is to open a second GridView (`gvDetail`) in a modal window based on row information from `gvSummary`.

The problem I am having is that I can't seem to execute the code in `gvSummary_RowCommand` by clicking the button `btnOpen`. I can execute the code from the `<asp:ButtonField>` but this doesn't open the second GridView.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSummary" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlgvSummary" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
OnRowDataBound="gvSummary_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="gvSummary_RowCommand" CssClass="table table-hover table-bordered" EmptyDataText="No data to display." >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ClientRef" HeaderText="Reference No."/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="InsertedWhen" HeaderText="Transaction Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Commodity" HeaderText="Commodity" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StartDate" HeaderText="Settlement Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EndDate" HeaderText="Delivery Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Value" HeaderText="Transaction Value" DataFormatString="{0:N2}" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Fee" HeaderText="Fee" DataFormatString="{0:N2}" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="InsertedBy" HeaderText="Purchased By" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="cmdDetail1" HeaderText="View Details" Text="View" ControlStyle-CssClass="openModal"/>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnOpen" runat="server" Text="Show Gridview" CssClass="openModal" CommandName="cmdDetail2"/>
                        <div class="modal" id="idModal">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h1>Transaction Details<a class="close-modal" href="#">&times;</a></h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <asp:GridView ID="gvDetail" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlgvDetail" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                    OnRowDataBound="gvDetail_RowDataBound" CssClass="table table-hover table-bordered" EmptyDataText="No data to display." >
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="metalid" HeaderText="Metal ID"/>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="enddate" HeaderText="End Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="startdate" HeaderText="Start Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="clientref" HeaderText="Client Ref" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" DataFormatString="{0:N2}" />
                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <asp:Button ID="btn_close" runat="server" Text="OK" CssClass="close-modal btn-sm btn-primary"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="modal-backdrop"></div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void gvSummary_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    string name = e.CommandName.ToString();
    string clientRef = gvSummary.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text;
    Response.Write("<br> index = " + index);
    Response.Write("<br> name = " + name);
    Response.Write("<br> clientRef = " + clientRef);

    SqlgvDetail.SelectCommand = " SELECT td.metalid , td.enddate , td.startdate , td.clientref , td.quantity " +
                                " FROM trxdetail td " +
                                " WHERE td.clientref = " + "'" + clientRef + "'";
}
```

When I click the `<asp:ButtonField>`, the SQL is correct and the Response.Write() sets the correct variables in `gvSummary_RowCommand`. However, the modal window doesn't open.

When I click `btnOpen`, the modal window opens but does not set the variables in `gvSummary_RowCommand`.

I can't seem to be able to egt this working so any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: based on your tags you're trying to implement a bootstrap modeal?  if so  don't see a [`data-target`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage) attribute in any of the buttons.  See this [Bootstrap Modal Usage](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage)

Comment: Also - keep in mind that a postback is going to obliterate the modal call -bootstrap modal is activated clientside

Comment: if you want to pop open a bootstrap modal, you're going to have to either prepopulate the inner gridview for each row and keep it hidden within a containing div, or on open make an ajax call that returns the data that you can then arrange or use to populate some form of clientside grid system